# ade4 package - principal component analysis

Tags: r, pca

I intend to to some principal component analysis and I am using this [PCA tutorial](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf) as a guide. I have the following code:

```
library("ade4")
Data <- read.table("D:/Bla/Data1.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")    
plot(Data$X, Data$Y)
pc <- dudi.pca(Data, scale = FALSE, scan = FALSE)    
pc$eig
```

However, I just don't get the some eigen values as the ones in the tutorial. Am I doing something wrong or does `dudi.pca` have known 'issues'? BTW how do I obtain the eigen vectors?

PS:

I used this data:

```
X   Y
2.5 2.4
0.5 0.7
2.2 2.9
1.9 2.2
3.1 3
2.3 2.7
2   1.6
1   1.1
1.5 1.6
1.1 0.9
```

which `dudi.pca` normalises by substracting the mean.

Comment: I just noticed that it does the pca correctly but normalises the data by substracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pdf you linked to, the eigenvalues are obtained via the command:

```
eigen(cov(Data))
```

whereas the eigenvalues from `dudi.pca` (I presume), come from the centred and scaled covariance matrix.